# Navigation Menu not showing on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, menu

I have a website I am working on. Everything is working perfectly on the laptop version of the website but when I test it on my phone MENU doesn't show up.

[mcffoundation](http://mcffoundation.org)

Thank You

Comment: See [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/4642212). Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mcve], including all _errors_, and demonstrate _your research and your attempts_ and explain what precisely didn’t work.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is on your source

`.visible-lg, .visible-md, .visible-sm, .visible-xs{display:none!important;}`

=>> **bootsrap.css:6554 & bootstrap.css:5671 i.e,.** do check these lines.